# Pointers to structure

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Well I was going through a C book Let us C, and was reading pointer to Structures according to the book's diagrammatical representation the pointer of the structure points to the beginning of the structure e.g.

```
strcut b
{ 
    char name[25];
    char author[25];
    int callno;
}b1,*ptr;



b1.name      b1.author  b1.callno   
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
: Let Us c    :  YPK       : 101           :    
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
4001        4026        4051




   ptr
::::::::::
: 4001   :  
::::::::::
   8000
```

The above is the memory representation where 4001,8000 and so are memory address. Now if the ptr points to 4001 by default, Shouldn't then
**b1.name** and **ptr->name** have the same memory address and also **b1.author** and **ptr->author** have the same memory address

Comment: Don't read `Let us C` - its a non standard book.

Comment: Then which book should I recommend ?

Comment: @CoolGuy but I am getting different address for them :/

Comment: Show the rest of the code, it's not clear what `ptr` is initialized to..

Comment: At which point do you create relation between b1 and ptr? Why do you expect them to be connected in any way?

Comment: Show the code. Are you using `&b1.name` to get the address? If so, then that is wrong. Use `b1.name` to get the correct address

Comment: Sorry there was a typo I just realized I've made the correction

Comment: Here is the code http://ideone.com/cnWDP6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This record

```
strcut b
{ 
    char name[25];
    char author[25];
    int callno;
}b1,*ptr;
```

is equivalent to

```
strcut b
{ 
    char name[25];
    char author[25];
    int callno;
};

struct b b1;
struct b *ptr;
```

As you can see variable ptr was not initialized if these definitions define local variables. If they define variables with the static storage duration (global variables) then  ptr will be initialized by NULL.

> Shouldn't then b1.name and ptr->name have the same memory address and
>   also b1.author and b1->ptr have the same memory address

They had the same address if the original definition would be written like

```
strcut b
{ 
    char name[25];
    char author[25];
    int callno;
}b1,*ptr = &b1
```

That is if ptr were initialized by the address of b1.

Answer (score 3):

No.

```
struct b
{ 
    char name[25];
    char author[25];
    int callno;
}b1,*ptr;
```

This creates an object `b1` of type `struct b`, and a pointer `ptr` to type `struct b`. The two variables `b1` and `ptr` are not related to each other.

Answer (score 3):

No,`b1` and `ptr` are two different variables stored at different location.

`b1` is base address of `struct b1` of type `struct b`.

`ptr` is a `pointer to a structure` of type `b`.

Now if you write : `ptr = &b1`;

Then `ptr` holds address of `b1`.

Now ,bye  De-referencing `ptr` you can access members of `b1`.

Comment: Isn't `ptr = b1` supposed to be `ptr = &b1`?

Comment: @vagish no, `error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘struct b *’ from type ‘struct b’` is the compiler error for `ptr = b1;`.

Answer (score 1):

b1.name and ptr -> name are having same address.
Similary b1.author and ptr -> author are having same address.

Following program can be used to demonstrate this concept;

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct b
{
        char name[25];
        char author[25];
        int callno;
}b1, *ptr;

int main()
{


    ptr = &b1;

    printf("%p %p\n", (void *)b1.name, (void *)ptr->name);
        printf("%p %p\n", (void *)b1.author, (void *)ptr -> author);
    printf("%p %p\n", (void *)&(b1.callno), (void *)&(ptr -> callno));  
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you should use `%p` and a cast to `(void*)` to print the value of a pointer.